# Angularjs currency format ₺ (Turkish Lira)?

Tags: angularjs

How to change angularjs currency format? I need to change like this
`2.543.128,76` . Default angularjs format `$254,312,876.00`.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to add the right local like `<script src="i18n/angular-locale_tr-tr.js"></script>`

supported locales are here : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale

you could also do it with number filter :

```
{{(produce.price | number:2) + "₺"}}
```

Comment: Actually, There are no standards for Turkey. I need to only change currency format. like this http://numeraljs.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ product.price | currency: "₺"}}
```

Comment: Will this also use commas as the decimal separator and period as the group separator instead of the reverse?

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.